# how to jump between pages with params while not changing the url

Tags: javascript, html

recently,i met with a problem that.

there is one page:pageA,there are some  in it. the url of which will lead u to another page:pageB .

however ,i want to jump with some params or data while not changing the url of the pageB. is there any good solutions? i'm using react,but not a single page project.

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of ways of doing it like using `cookies`, `spring webflow`(if its spring application ) or using `Local/Session` Storage

[Web Storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API) is a feasible and an easy approach

In page A you can store the value in a local storage using key & value

```
if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
    localStorage.setItem("anyunique Key Name ", "value which you want to store");
} else {
    // Sorry! No Web Storage support..
}
```

In page B use same `LocalStorage's getItem()` method to retrieve the value

```
document.getElementById("someDOM").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("key");
```

Comment: first,cookies,the safety and compacity maybe a consideration.second,it's a  react project(front-end).third,is there any limitations of using this method?eg,the storage compacity? also,i wanna know if i send a ajax with params in the current page and when i got the response,i replace the href to pageB? is it feasible?

Comment: storage capacity is around 10MB per origin & yes you can update the value

Comment: so both methods are ok? um..the project is for mobile and i wanno know if it's bad to hold for some large data with storage?